# Google Admob ads are not working when publish my Unity game on Google Play

Tags: unity-game-engine, admob

My Admob ads are implemented just like on 100s of tutorials.Everything is implemented so fine and works fine in Unity play mode,and works fine when test it on real device when directly build and run,on few real mobile devices.But when i publish my app Ads are not showing.I simply dont get why and how it is possible.What am I missing?If someone has even Idea about what is here,pls write.
P.S I already published 9 apps and games and never had such problem

Answer (score 0):

No mistakes on your part. When you publish your game, AdMob takes some time to collect significant data about your user audience and your product. AdMob also making some magical stuff during this period, let's say AdMob is tuning your ads. In my case it took a week for the ad to start showing. Don't worry! Your ads will appear soon!